# Different colorisation for Json properties and values

Tags: notepad++

Using N++ to quickly inspect Json, I have the following issue:
Everything has the same color. Properties / Text Values.

In the N++ *Style Configurator*, there is no option for Value and Property Name. It's just String single quote or double quote.

Have to have a better color and readability?

#### Exemple :

For the following Json:

```
{"description":{"title":"Contiguous U.S., Average Temperature","units":"Degrees Fahrenheit","base_period":"1901-2000"},"data":{"189512":{"value":"50.34","anomaly":"-1.68"},"189612":{"value":"51.99","anomaly":"-0.03"},"189712":{"value":"51.56","anomaly":"-0.46"}}}
```

N++ and an online tool will have really different coloring :

[image]

In N++, your eyes must look for the `:` then roll back to read the property name. Especially on multiline data (indented and auto carriage return so you don't horizontal scroll into infinity).

Online tool (Don't min the dark theme)  is really more readable by having more different colors.

Comment: Click `Language` -> `J` -> `JSON`. It should auto apply the styles to your document

Comment: May I ask why the down vote? I know N++ is not Vim or an EDI. But simple parsing and highlight is not high evolution. Is the question not legitimate ("You don't have to do that. Copy past in your other editor that does proper higlight")? To basic - no research(Use the standard higtlight)?

Comment: update from 2020. notepad++ pushed a big update. That use the new Scintilla 4.Something  that will give a more usefull colorisation. It's not pretty but it's at least usable. It has to many issue when you try to edit the default color but at least it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Scintilla](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/) component used by Notepad++ is in charge of the lexers for syntax highlighting.  Apparently, the designer of that lexer didn't decide to differentiate between property names and values, though it seems like a good idea.  To make a suggestion for that improvement in the lexer, you'd have to go see if the most recent Scintilla JSON Lexer has already incorporated that change, and if not, put in a [request](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/bugs/) with the Scintilla project.  If the change is already there, or if Scintilla releases a new version with that fix for you, you would then have to [ask Notepad++ developer](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) to upgrade Scintilla to include that fix.  (And the last time NPP [upgraded it's Scintilla](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/tree/master/scintilla) was from 3.34 to 3.56 -- about 4 years ago -- compared to the most-recent Scintilla 4.1.3)

Workaround #1: change the **Style Configurator > JSON > Operator** color to have something that stands out between the property and value -- maybe with a bright yellow background or something -- to make it easier for your eye to find the `:` separators, at least...

Workaround #2: In the [Community Forums](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/), Claudia Frank had done some work on a PythonScript-based lexer which would allow user defined languages with regular expressions, rather than the simplistic UDL 2.1. My collection of links to her effort is at https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/16164/bug-javascript-multiline-character-not-understood-by-notepad/11.  With some effort, you might be able to define the regex necessary to parse JSON in a way you like.

---

**update**: You might be able to get a UDL (User Defined Language) to do what you want.  I came up with a quick one that will get the highlighting differences you described.  As a nasty side effect, it breaks folding (so cannot collapse `{ ... }` pairs.  (I tried setting the UDL folding options, but nested folds weren't working right, at least on my first attempt)

- **Language > Define Your Language...**: **Create New** = JsonPropertyValues.
- **Operators & Delimiters**
- **Operators 1** = `, : " ' { }`, STYLER = set whatever colors you want for the punctuation
- **Delimiter 1 style** = OPEN: `:`, Close = `((EOL))`, STYLER = set the color you want the VALUE side to be; set `Nesting:` to allow `Operators 1`
- **Delimiter 2 style** = OPEN: `"`, Close = `"`, STYLER = set the color for left-side (property) when in double-quotes, no nesting needed
- **Delimiter 3 style** = OPEN: `'`, Close = `'`, STYLER = set the color for left-side (property) when in single-quotes, no nesting needed

You might want to set `Nesting:` to include `Numbers` on all of those STYLER entries above.  And then go to the **Comment & Number** tab and define the STYLER to set the coloring for numbers as well.

You could set the **Ext** box to `json`, if you want it to apply to all `.JSON` files, or you could just manually apply **Language > JsonPropertyValues** to any JSON that you want to parse in this manner.

Anyway, this is a reasonable starting point, based on what you described; feel free to customize it or expand it beyond the features included.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was out of the SO for a week. This look Excellent. Thanks for you time crafting this answer. I will try both posibility.

Answer (score 1):

*Method 1:*

**Settings > Style Configurator > Global Syles (Language) > Global override (Style) > Enable global background colour**

This did it for me.

P.S.: my selected theme was *DarkModeDefault*, but it doesn't matter since it depends on enabling the Global Styles settings you wish)

P.S.2:

*Method 2:*

**Settings > Preferences > Dark Mode > Dark Mode (instead of Follow Windows / other OS)**